# Why isn't water running through our radiators?

Tags: hvac, heating, thermostat, boiler, radiator

We had a plumber in today to bleed our rads. He also changed the batteries on the thermostat and fiddled around with the boiler. Since he left the temperature has dropped dramatically and he's refused to come back stating there is nothing he can do. HELP!
When we turn on the thermostat, the boiler kicks in, but we aren't getting any hot water running into the rads.
Is it the thermostat?
Any suggestions welcome, or it's going to be a cold night!

Comment: It may help you to get an answer if you can provide more information about your home heating system.

Comment: If the boiler turns on, it's likely not a problem with the thermostat.  Was the plumber called because the heat wasn't working, or was it just a regular maintenance call? Is there only one plumber in your area, or could you contact a different plumber?

Comment: is the circulation pump working?

Comment: Regardless of the problem, it seems as if things were working before the plumber came and stopped after his visit. So he should be held liable. If he refuses then have another plumber fix the issue and take the first plumber to court.

Comment: Air-locks (excessive air in the closed system) can impede water flow. The process for removing air locks is to raise the pressure and bleed the air from the system.